# Can someone tell me why the a:hover doesn't work?

Tags: html, css, hover

The `:hover` doesn't work and I don't know why.

You should know that I have reduced my original code to these few lines. But each of them is useful like the "content" div.

If I delete `width:100%;` or `position:fixed;` it works, but I don't know why 
(I can't remove those lines because I use them in the original web site)

```css
#content {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  position: fixed;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
}

a {
  width: 100%;
}

a:hover {
  font-size: 23pt;
}
```

```html
<a>HOME</a>
<div id="content">
</div>
```

Comment: It looks like `#content` will cover the `<a>` tag, blocking its pointer events. You can change this by setting a higher [`z-index`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/z-index) on the `<a>` tag or by disabling [`pointer-events`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/pointer-events) on `#content`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `#content` div is taken out of the normal DOM painting flow due to `position:fixed` and becomes positioned on top of the anchor tag.

An easy way to solve this is to set a negative `z-index` on content.

```css
#content {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  position: fixed;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  z-index:-1;
}

a {
  width: 100%;

}

a:hover {
  font-size: 23pt;
}
```

```html
<a>HOME</a>
<div id="content">
</div>
```

Comment: `z-index: -1` will hide `#content` from page.

Comment: @HassanSiddiqui put a background on the content div, it is still visible.

Answer (score 3):

It's because `fixed` element is above your `<a>`. Put `z-index` for it.

```css
#content {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    position: fixed;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, .3);
    z-index: 5;
}

a {
    width: 100%;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 6;
}

a:hover {
    font-size: 23pt;
}
```

```html
<a>HOME</a>
<div id="content">
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just move your anchor to be rendered **after** your *fixed* div, and set your anchor to have **`position: absolute`** so it can be rendered upon the div

```css
#content {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  position: fixed;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
}

a {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
}

a:hover {
  font-size: 23pt;
}
```

```html
<div id="content">
</div>
<a>HOME</a>
```

---

Working with multiple possitive z-indexes (which also seems to *solve* that issue at first time) is a bit *tricky* when setting z-indexes to multiple elements, and can lead you to undesired situations once you start adding more and more elements to your dom, and will be forced to set specific z-indexes for every new element (taking care to change everytime the z-index number to avoid new "overlapping-element" situations

Comment: And setting position absolute will be more of a pain when it comes to resizing the browser and making it responsive and managing content around/with the anchor tag. Each have their pros and cons

Comment: Making link `position: absolute;` will bring more issues than good behavior.

Comment: You're right, @GBWDev. Indeed, now thinking it twice, your proposal of using the negative z-index (instead of many possitive indexes) is quite better. I just don't like the fact of dealing with multiple z-indexes, but certainly by setting just -1 to the offending div is enough to solve it. :+1:

Comment: Updated my answer to express that point a bit better. Thanks @GBWDev

Comment: Note that `position:relative` on the `<a>` works, as well. In the absence of `z-index`, positioned elements are stacked "in order of appearance in the HTML". Non-positioned elements are stacked behind positioned elements so, without positioning, the `<a>` element is behind the positioned `#content`. See [Stacking without the z-index property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Positioning/Understanding_z_index/Stacking_without_z-index).